# Can not Evaluate property expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I uninstalled visual studio 2015 from my computer which I am not frequently using and I open my application developed in Visual Studio 2010 but it suddenly prompted below error. I repaired my Visual Studio even still I am facing same error please advise Thanks.

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found a solution finally!
Visual studio 2015 forgets one of its registry keys after you uninstall it.
I solved it by removing the "14" (2015) version folder from here: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions
and it worked fine!

Comment: Might be the answer but unfortunately it didn't worked for me so I installed VS 2015 again :(